# Split Line on TAB and Display in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been having a bit of issue with some code. I have a '.log' file that I would like to show each column of the file in a different column of the GridView. I have tried the following code but it just produces a single column and then place all the data in it. Can anyone spot what is going wrong with my code. Or is there a better way to load the log file into a web page so that I can see the data and convert the TimeData stamp to normal TimeDate format so that we can understand the log file better.

```
  private static DataTable GetDataTableFromFile(string csvfilePath)
    {
        DataTable fileData = new DataTable();
        using (TextFieldParser fileReader = new TextFieldParser(csvfilePath))
        {
            fileReader.SetDelimiters(new String[] { "\t" });
            fileReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            //Read columns from CSV file, remove this line if columns not exits  
            string[] colFields = fileReader.ReadFields();

            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                fileData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }

            while (!fileReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = fileReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                fileData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
        }
        return fileData;
    }
```

Any suggestion would be excellent.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the standard libraries such as [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx), then you could use [Loupe](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/Loupe)

Even if you don't use one of the standard logging libraries, you can still write your own parser so that Loupe can handle your file formats.

It's perhaps better to make use of this existing software as it can probably do what you want, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about number of delimiters Tab are same in each line then you can do something like this (in `while loop`):

```
while (!fileReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = fileReader.ReadFields();

            if(fieldData.Length > 0)
            {
               DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();               
               for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
               {                   
                   dr[i] =  fieldData[i];
               }
               fileData.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
```